# Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm not sure why `this.model` is undefined in my backbone view.

Here's my script:

```
var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    f_Name: "Darth"
  },

  parse: function(response) {
    console.log('parsing');
  }

});

var TheView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.js-container',

  intialize: function() {
    this.model = new TheModel(); 
    debugger;
  },

  template: _.template( $('#form-template').html() ),

  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.html( this.template({settings: this.model.toJSON()}) );

    return this;
  }
});

var theView = new TheView();
theView.render();
```

Here's my templates:

```
<div class="js-container">

</div>

<script type="text/template" id="form-template">
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <form action="" method="Post">
    <div>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="fName" />
    </div>
  </form>

  <div>
    Name = <%- settings.f_Name %>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: try `self.model.toJSIN()`

Comment: It's a typo : `intialize` vs `initialize` (missing i) in your view definition. http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/hdxoc4tu/14/

Comment: @nikoshr Thank you!  Sorry for posting such a simple miss on my part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled 'initialize' wrong